# AIを使用すれば「部品の分類」を実現できるかどうか

Tags: 機械学習

AIについて分かっておらず、以下のようなことを、AIを使用すれば実現できるかお聞きしたいです。

#### 行いたいこと

様々な部品に対して、キーワードを登録しており、一定数のサンプルデータ（教師データ？）から新しい部品に対するキーワードを自動作成する。

例えば、Webサイトで、様々な部品（部品名や型式やメーカ名も含む）を登録します。また、それらのデータをDBに蓄積させます。
その後、一定数のサンプルデータを取得できれば、DBのデータを元にAIの解析を使用して、新しい部品登録から、その部品のキーワードを自動作成可能かどうかです(その後、部品リストに部品とそのキーワードを表示させていくようなイメージです)。

サンプルデータが以下として、新しく登録された部品Cのキーワードが、「LANケーブル」として自動生成・表示されるかどうかです。

部品Aのキーワード：同軸ケーブル/5m/
部品Bのキーワード：LANケーブル/3m/

何となく厳しそうな気がしていますが、教えていただければ助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 商品名のデータベースから頻出単語を見つける、ということでしょうか？いわゆるAIを使うよりも自然言語処理技術を使うほうが適切（高速で、高精度）な気がしますが……

Comment: 説明は簡略化しているのだと思われますが、新しい部品がなぜ同軸ケーブルではなくLANケーブルとして選ばれるのかが分かりませんでした。AIに限らずとも、複数の属性から類推させること自体は恐らく実現可能かと思われます。

Comment: 説明変数は何でしょうか？

Comment: @PicoSushi ご連絡ありがとうございます。部品Aや部品Bと記載しましたが具体的に、品名、その商品の型式、「自社のどの製品に使用されるか」、メーカ名等は項目としてあるので、それらを変数として使用できればと思います。一度自然言語について調べて見ます、、

Comment: @cubick  ご連絡ありがとうございます。具体的ではなく申し訳ございません。例は簡略して参考程度に示しただけ理由は特にありません。上記の項目（変数）を元に、キーワードを推定して、生成できればと思います。
例えば、品名、型式、「自社のどの製品に使用されるか」、メーカで作成すれば、
・ケーブル、AAAA-1111、製品XXX 、メーカA社   →部品A
・ケーブル、BB-123、製品XXX、メーカB社　　　 →部品B

というような感じでしょうか。これらの項目（変数）と、各部品で作成したキーワードを元に、新規部品のキーワードを類推できればと思います。
こういった方法は自然言語処理技術になりそうでしょうか？

Comment: @merino ご連絡ありがとうございます。上記で示したように品名、型式、「自社のどの製品に使用されるか」、メーカを現状考えています。

Comment: 分類問題と捉えると変数が少ないほど難しくなるかと思います。まずはロジスティック回帰などで試してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: @merino  変数が4つとなると少ないんですね、、ロジスティックス回帰は、特定の事象が発生する確率を予測時に使用するのかと思いますが、今回は何が発生する確率を調べるべきなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

書かれている内容について、いくつかのAIの組み合わせで実現できると思います。
まずは、利用する２種類のAIの仕組みを簡単に解説します。
これらを適切に組み合わせることで、問題が解決できると考えます。

### ・自然言語処理用AI（例：Word2Vec）

1． AIに意味を分類したいキーワード（キーワード候補自体が分類時の入力変数に入っていない場合は分類につかう変数も）が含まれる教材を使って学習させます。これによって、AIは各キーワードを「多次元ベクトル」（意味ベクトル）へ変換できるようになります。AIは、各キーワードの内、似ているものを似ているベクトルに変換するようになります。それらは「近い意味である」と学習しているためです。

２．「LAN」などの、キーワード候補として取り扱いたいワードをあらかじめ全てベクトルに変換しておきます。これは後の計算で使います。分類用のキーワードが形態素解析などによって複数に分割出来る場合は、ベクトルを合成すると簡単な場合があります。
例えば、「LAN」＋「ケーブル」というように複数の意味ベクトルを合成すると、結果のベクトルには「LAN」と「ケーブル」のどちらの意味も含まれます。ただし、あまり合成する数が多いと意味がぼやけやすくなるのと、「LAN」とも「ケーブル」とも類似になるので注意は必要です。

３．新しく登録する際に、分類したい部品の情報（例えば新しく登録された部品Cに関する情報）をベクトルに変換します。
ここで使う情報はなるべくノイズを減らす方が良いので、分類したい内容的に無意味な情報は使わないようにします。

４．２と３のベクトル同士の類似度を「ベクトル同士の距離」や「ベクトル同士の角度の差」などの数学的な計算によって算出します。ベクトルの計算のみなのでこれは非常に高速であり、合成したベクトルでも同様に計算できます。

５．４で最も類似であると計算されたキーワード候補が、分類したい部品に対して自動作成されるキーワードになります。

### ・ロジスティック回帰系AI（例：多層パーセプトロンで、出力層をロジスティック（シグモイド）関数の多変量版であるソフトマックス関数にしたもの）

１．このAIは基本的に入力が0と1の組み合わせが配列になったデータであり、予め入力内容を定義出来る場合に使用します。

２．例として、分類対象の部品を以下とおきます。（部品Cが分類対象で、Bと全く同じデータになっていますが、実際には学習したデータのバリエーション次第でBと全く同じでなくとも大丈夫です）
部品A｛品名：○○同軸ケーブル,型式：A-111,自社のどの製品に使用されるか：製品X,メーカー：○○電機｝
部品B｛品名：○○LANケーブル,型式：B-111,自社のどの製品に使用されるか：製品Y,メーカー：○○商事｝
部品C｛品名：○○LANケーブル,型式：B-111,自社のどの製品に使用されるか：製品Y,メーカー：○○商事｝

３．まず全ての変数（「品名」、「型式」、「自社のどの製品に使用されるか」、「メーカ」のバリエーション）を洗い出します。「品名」にパターンが多すぎるような場合は、「品名」部分では自然言語処理用AIを用いるか、形態素解析後に品名分類用の辞書（作成可能な場合）とマッチングさせるべきなので、今回は簡単のために「品名」を除外します。
なので、パターンは以下の通りです。
[A-111,B-111,製品X,製品Y,○○電機,○○商事]

４．部品の属性のうち、先ほどのパターンとマッチする部分を1にした配列を作成します。
例えば部品Aは
[1,0,1,0,1,0]
です。
これがAIの学習の時と、新しい部品を追加して実際に分類する時に使う、AIへの入力作成方法です。

５．AIに、既存のデータにある部品Aと部品Bについて学習させます。
教師データ（AIにパターンを教えるために作る必要のあるデータ）の例は以下の通りです。
{入力（部品A）：[1,0,1,0,1,0],出力：[1,0]}
{入力（部品B）：[0,1,0,1,0,1],出力：[0,1]}
ここで、
出力が[1,0]だった場合を{長さ:5m,色:銀色}、
出力が[0,1]だった場合を{長さ:3m,色:赤色}、
とします。このように特定の配列に対応する辞書をあらかじめ作成しておきます。

６．新しく分類したい、部品CをAIで分類します。
部品Cは入力が[0,1,0,1,0,1]なので出力は[0,1]となり、辞書から{長さ:3m,色:赤色}というキーワードが得られます。

### 上記２つのAIの併用

部品の変数である、「品名」、「型式」、「自社のどの製品に使用されるか」、「メーカ」の内、「品名」を自然言語処理用AIで、それ以外をロジスティック回帰系AIで処理し、結果を結合します。
部品Cの場合では、自然言語処理用AIの結果から不要なワード「○○」が取り除かれた「LANケーブル」というキーワードが得られます。
同様に、ロジスティック回帰系AIの結果からは{長さ:3m,色:赤色}という結果が得られます。

**これを組み合わせて得られる部品Cの結果キーワードは以下となります。**
LANケーブル/3m/赤色

この方法によって、AIでこの問題を解決できると思います。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。例えば、今回使用する変数は他のコメントでも記載させていただきましたが、品名、型式、「自社のどの製品に使用されるか」、メーカとしてます。部品Cの各変数を組み合わせてベクトル変換を行いまいす。そして、その結果と部品Bの変数の組み合わせによるベクトル変換の結果の類似度が高いので、キーワードがLANケーブルであると判定されるのでしょうか？

Comment: おっとすみません、ちょっと勘違いしていて、回答が変なことになっています。夜になりますがご回答を含めて修正しますので、しばらくお待ち下さい。

Comment: 回答を修正しました。おっしゃるとおり、部品Bと部品Cの各変数をそれぞれ合成したベクトルが類似であるならば、部品Cには、部品Bと同じキーワードが生成されます。

Comment: 自然言語処理用のAIを使う場合の注意点なのですが、変数には「品名」などの人間が見て意味がわかる内容を使う必要があります。また、おっしゃられている変数からすると、学習用の適切な教材があるかどうかも焦点になるかもしれません。「品名」が「LANケーブル」などであればいけそうですが、「記号の羅列のみ」のようなものだったりすると分類出来る可能性は低いです。

Comment: お忙しいところ解説していただきありがとうございます。M.M.さんの手法をもう少し勉強していきたいと思います。もう2点ですが、部品の項目として、「記号の羅列のみ」を示す型番を変数として採用すべきではないでしょうか（内容によって、判別できそうな型番もありますが）？そして、キーワードが複数ある場合（部品Aのキーワード：同軸ケーブル/5m/銀色　等）も判別できそうでしょうか？

Comment: まず１つ目のご質問ですが、「記号の羅列のみ」を示す型番などを変数として採用したい場合は、「自然言語処理」をからめた処理よりも、merinoさんのコメントにあるロジスティック回帰（多クラス分類）や他の種類のAI(SVMなど)を使用する方が良いです。この場合はあらかじめ自作した教師データを使っての学習が必要になりますが、似た型番などでも判別できます。
ロジスティック回帰などの問題は主にこの教師データの作成であり、大抵の場合はあらかじめどういう変数があるのか大体分かっている場合にだけ利用出来ます。
つまり、新しく追加される部品の変数が既存のどれかである場合であり、変数の数が増減しない場合に有用です。
私の回答の方は学習教材になるのが主に文章であり、あらかじめどういう変数が与えられるか分からなくてもそれなりに使えるメリットがありますが、型番や数字のみの項目などは大抵ノイズになります。
例えば「ABC123」などの型番や「500円」などのような数字情報は、「親」と「子」のような言葉の意味上の関係性を持っていないので大抵はベクトル空間中に上手く配置できないんです。

Comment: ２つ目ですが、得たい部品のキーワードが「同軸ケーブル/5m/銀色」の場合など、名前以外の部分のバリエーションが豊富になる場合、自然言語のみでやるのが厳しくなってくると思います。
入力データがコメントの方であった「品名、型式、自社のどの製品に使用されるか、メーカ」であれば、自然言語では「品名」か「品名とメーカ」でケーブルの種類などを分類して、色などの固定データの推測は「型式、自社のどの製品に使用されるか、メーカ」からロジスティック回帰を使うと上手くいくと思います。
用途次第で、いくつかのAIを組み合わせるのはよくやります。
ただ、「品名」も特定の種類のみ存在するなら、ロジスティック回帰だけでもいけると思います。

Comment: なお、補足ですがロジスティック回帰による多クラス分類では、「型式」、「自社のどの製品に使用されるか」、「メーカ」などの組み合わせから、「5m/銀色」や「3m/赤色」などの付加情報の内、一番確率が高いものが「5m/銀色」である、というような推測が出来ます。
これは、ロジスティック回帰の学習で「型式」、「自社のどの製品に使用されるか」、「メーカ」が特定の組み合わせの場合に、結果が「5m/銀色」であるという学習を事前に行う（行う必要がある）ためです。

Comment: 1つ目の内容についてですが、最初に教師データを作成しておき、その後教師データを常時更新して使用するということもされている方はいるでしょうか？変数の増減はないですが、部品データを新規登録して追加していくので、更新された教師データを
利用していく形です。新規登録を1回行う度に、教師データを更新して、すべての部品データのキーワードを更新するという方法は、処理に時間がかかるかと思います。よって、一定の部品データが追加された時に、まとめて全ての部品データを更新したいと思います。兎にも角にも、ロジスティックス回帰という方法が可能性としてあるんですね＾＾

Comment: 2つ目の内容について、キーワードを分けて判別し、出力できるでしょうか？M.Mさんのご提案の場合、新規登録したキーワードとして、教師データに登録したキーワードが全て出力されるかと
思います。例えば、この場合、新規登録したキーワードが「5m/銀色」、「3m/赤色」として出力されるのかと思います。
　そうではなく、新規登録したキーワードが、教師データの結果（この場合、部品A「5m/銀色」、部品B「3m/赤色」のデータ)から、「5m」だったり、「赤色」だったり、
部品A、Bが組み合わさって、「5m/赤色」として出力できるでしょうか？このような場合、教師データ作成時に、各部品のキーワードを個別に分解して、1.部品「5m」、2.部品A「銀色」として認識させれば、できそうでしょうか？変数のデータは同じですが、その答えが複数あるということです。色々と次から次へと質問して申し訳ございません。

Comment: １つ目ですが、教師データを更新して利用していくという形はよくあります。 ロジスティック回帰を使ったAIの教師データについての注意点ですが、これはAIに対し、人に教えるように個別で答えを教える必要があります。 そうすることで、次からはAIは同じ問題を解けるようになります。 なので、新規登録時の組み合わせが新規パターンであれば（自動分類結果がおかしい表示になっているなら）、新しい教師データの追加が必要です。 そして、一定の部品データが追加された時にこれらをまとめて処理すると良いと思います。元のご質問がロジスティック回帰などを含めて回答したほうが良い問題だと思いますので、後からご覧になった人のためにも、後ほど回答の方にも簡単な例を加えます。

Comment: ２つ目は、私の方がsantianさんのなさりたい内容をあまりよく分かっていないような気がしますが、AIの出力が対応するものを辞書形式にして、Aだったら{長さ:5m,色:銀色},Bだったら{長さ:3m,色:赤色}というような出力はできます。この結果の組み合わせから更に条件がある場合（条件で結果を統合して{5m/赤色}のようにする場合）はその部分は普通のプログラムで処理するほうが簡単な気がします。もちろん、ここも別のAIにすることも出来ますが。
教師データは後ほど回答に例で加えますので、それをご覧いただくと分かりやすいと思います。

Comment: 修正して解説していただき本当にありがとうございます！2つ目について、別の例をお伝えすると、キーワードの登録個数も、種類もランダムな場合、その後正しく反映できるのかどうかお聞きしたいです。M.M.さんに教えていただいた手法では、キーワード（出力）の内容が固定でした（「長さ」と「色」が必ず存在するということです）。
しかし、部品の登録者は複数人おり、キーワードの登録内容も、その人の考えに依存します。例えば、
部品Aのキーワード（5m/銀色）
部品Bのキーワード（3m）
部品Cのキーワード（0.5m/15pin/6mm） 

のような感じです。キーワードの種類や個数が違います。
今回の手法の場合、入力の変数は確かに固定されておりますが、出力も種類を固定しなければならないでしょうか？自然言語処理側も同様に、キーワードの種類や個数がバラバラな場合いかがでしょうか、、？

Comment: 出力に関して、出力と対応したキーワードの内容に含まれる要素数などを固定する必要は無く、新しいパターンが増えたら[0,0,1]のように、出力時の配列の数を増やしていきます。
以前の辞書や教師データの更新などは[1,0,0]（元データは[1,0]）などのように最後を0で埋めるだけです。
ただし、AIそのものは初期化して再度学習させる方が良いです。複雑な方法で前のデータを使いまわせますが、回答のAIなら設計と学習量次第ではすぐ学習が終わります。
自然言語処理側については、キーワードの種類や個数の影響がある程度自動で排除できます。
自動処理のみだと上手くいかない場合には、新しい部品登録時などのAIへの入力をプログラムで調整（フィルタリングなど）すると良いと思います。

Comment: 承知しました。大きな方向性は、M.Mさんのおかげで見えてきたと思います。もう少し理解を深めながら、手を動かしていければと思います。また、投稿することもあるかと思いますが、また分かりそうな内容であれば、お助けください。

Comment: いえいえ。お役にたてたようで良かったです。
ご利用の言語やライブラリ次第ではまた私が回答させていただくこともあるかもしれません。ではでは。